# Yii2 success modal window

Tags: ajax, yii2, modal-dialog

In view I have a form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Name'])->label(false) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Phone'])->label(false) ?>

    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Controller is:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Created');
    } 
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

Then in view I put a modal:

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')) :?>
    <!-- <div class="container">
        <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success', null, true) ?>
    </div> -->
    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p><?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success', null, true) ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ;?>
```

And JS code is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```

I want to open success modal window after clicking submit button. But now nothing happens. Just reloads the page. How to do that I want? And please explain how to do that without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

This might be no the best decidion, but i use class myAjaxModalClass and a simple js code, that submit all form with that class via ajax and parse json result:

{result:0, data:'new modal content'}

That allows me to load form with validation erros without page reloading. Also you may add your result status to submit redirect. Expample:

{result: 2, url:'http://yoursite.net'}